# checking whether the function can be holomorphically extended

Tags: complex-analysis

How to check whether the following functions can be holomorphically extended to $0$:
$z\cot(z)$, $z/e^{z}-1$,    $z^{2}\sin(1/z)$.

I just know if that a function is bounded on the neighbourhood of $0$ then it can be, but I do not how to check whether it is bounded or not.

Comment: One possible way to do it would be to work out the Laurent series expansion. If it has no negative power terms, then the function can be holomorphically extended to 0; if a negative power term appears, it can't be.

To your second question - one way to check whether a function is bounded at a neighborhood of 0: Does a limit exist as $z \to 0$? If it does, the function *must* be bounded near 0.